# Is there a constant expression for the string length of a numeric constant that does not use the preprocessor?

Tags: c++

Given a numeric constant such as `UINT64_MAX`, what is a constant expression for the length of the decimal string (*e.g.*, "18446744073709551615")?

Here's one that uses the preprocessor to stringify the constant:

```cpp
#define stringify(x) #x
constexpr size_t maxlen {std::char_traits<char>::length(stringify(UINT64_MAX))};
```

Is there a constant expression that does *not* use the preprocessor?

`std::numeric_limits<T>` seems like it should help here, but

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::digits10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max_digits10 << std::endl;
}
```

prints

```
19
0
```

It's not clear that `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::digits10 + 1` is a general solution to the problem.

Comment: something like `ceil(log10(num))`?

Comment: Well, if you need a `constexpr` computation, write a [`constexpr` function](https://godbolt.org/z/88vqY9rcE) to perform it.

Comment: Who says `UINT64_MAX` is a decimal string? Why not `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`? Or `~0ULL`? Or something else? (I'm sure the standard might disallow some versions, but I think you're already making some unwarranted assumptions)

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr size_t intlog10(T n) {
    size_t count = 0;
    while (n) {++count; n /= 10;}
    return count;
}

constexpr size_t maxlen=intlog10(UINT64_MAX);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GjWWT4KWz)

Comment: I like that this approach doesn't round down and so doesn't require the seemingly arbitrary `+ 1`, but maybe `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::digits10 + 1` is the simplest one-liner.

Comment: @claymation That works for the maximum representable value of that type, but it doesn't work for the length of all arbitrary constants.